# change the size of a CA factor map in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm doing a MCA analysis ,and I have found a plot graph.
But , I can't change the size of it  , does someone has an idea , please?

```
library("FactoMineR")
mca=CA(data_mca)
mca
plot.CA(mca,invisible = c("row"))#this line gives me the plot
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `windows()` and created the plot separately

```
library(FactoMineR)
data("decathlon")
mca=CA(decathlon,quanti.sup = 10:12,quali.sup = 13)

windows() # if you want to change the size then windows(width=10, height=4)
plot(res,choix="var", shadow = T, title="", cex = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.3)
```

Original plot:

[image]

```
library(FactoMineR)
    data("decathlon")
    mca=CA(decathlon,quanti.sup = 10:12,quali.sup = 13)
    
    windows(width=10, height=4) # changed the size and width
    plot(res,choix="var", shadow = T, title="", cex = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.3)
```

Adjusted plot:
[image]